# Adicionar Biblioteca externa .JAR, para projeto MAVEN usando VSCODE?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto JAVA juntamente com MAVEN para ser compilado. No entanto, estou precisando colocar a ***biblioteca.jar*** que já está no meu computador no projeto MAVEN e puxar os dados que está dentro dela para servir de complemento. Tipo o Netbeans, Eclipse, e outras IDE que tem suporte para isso.

Estou começando a usar o VSCODE, mas sei pouco dos recursos e ferramentas que a IDE  proporciona. Eu já instalei o MAVEN e os artefatos, já configurei as variáveis de ambiente. Mas adicionar uma dependência que já está no meu computador é o que não consigo. Eu só preciso colocar a biblioteca no meu projeto e usa-la.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para os casos em que a biblioteca é customizada, e não está disponível em nenhum repositório (interno da empresa ou da internet), você deve instalar o JAR localmente (para seu desenvolvimento).

A instalação no repositório local pode ser feita utilizando a seguinte sintaxe no prompt de comando:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Se o JAR foi criado utilizando Maven 2.5, voce pode simplesmente executar o seguinte comando que o Maven irá reconhecer o `pom.xml` que esta dentro do JAR e instalar ele corretamente:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

Após instalar o JAR você pode utilizar a dependência no seu POM normalmente.

**IMPORTANTE:** Lembre-se que como o JAR consta em seu repositório LOCAL, caso você tente realizar o build utilizando outra ferramenta fora do seu ambiente local (Jenkins, Bamboo...) **o JAR não estará disponível**, você deve lembrar de instalar ele também no repositório lido pelas ferramentas.

Você pode conferir a [documentação aqui](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

---

**UPDATE:** Estou complementando a resposta com base em suas demais perguntas.

Um exemplo de como instalar um novo JAR:

- Utilizando seu o *biblioteca.jar* como exemplo:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile="D:\Usuarios\ngueno\Desktop\biblioteca.jar" -DgroupId="com.ngueno" -DartifactId="biblioteca" -Dversion="1.0.0" -Dpackaging="jar"`

Onde:

> `file` - Caminho para o JAR à ser instalado
>
> `groupId`: Grupo relacionado ao artefato, geralmente definido pela empresa (um padrão é usar o site da empresa ao contrário)
>
> `artifactId`: Nome/Identificador do artefato
>
> `version`: Versão do artefato (utilizado para releases/snapshots)
>
> `packaging`: Tipo de empacotamento (JAR, WAR, EAR...)

Executando o comando de instalação, teremos o seguinte resultado:

```
λ mvn install:install-file -Dfile="D:\Usuarios\ngueno\Desktop\biblioteca.jar" -DgroupId="com.ngueno" -DartifactId="biblioteca" -Dversion="1.0.0" -Dpackaging="jar"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Usuarios\ngueno\Desktop\biblioteca.jar to C:\Users\ngueno\.m2\repository\com\ngueno\biblioteca\1.0.0\biblioteca-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ngueno\AppData\Local\Temp\mvninstall2369252046556360803.pom to C:\Users\ngueno\.m2\repository\com\ngueno\biblioteca\1.0.0\biblioteca-1.0.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.537 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-17T09:47:15-02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note que o JAR foi instalado no repositório local na log gerada pelo Maven:

`[INFO] Installing D:\Usuarios\ngueno\Desktop\biblioteca.jar to C:\Users\ngueno\.m2\repository\com\ngueno\biblioteca\1.0.0\biblioteca-1.0.0.jar`

E também foi gerado um `pom` para o artefato:

`[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ngueno\AppData\Local\Temp\mvninstall2369252046556360803.pom to C:\Users\ngueno\.m2\repository\com\ngueno\biblioteca\1.0.0\biblioteca-1.0.0.pom`

Para mais informações sobre a estrutura das dependências, [de uma olhada nesta documentação do Maven](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview) e neste [Overview sobre o Maven](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-model/maven.html#class_dependency).

Comment: Tenho que colocar no <group-id> <artifact-id> <version> <packaging> o mesmo quando criei o maven?

Comment: Não, ao instalar você vai inserir as informações do JAR que você está instalando, você pode definir qualquer nome. Você vai usar estas informações para incluir a dependência instalada no `pom.xml` do seu projeto atual.

Comment: Para que serve o packagin? E o que devo colocar nele? É que sou novo no Maven

Comment: @sYsTeM Complementando a explicação na resposta